# Separate apps in TestFlight for production and staging?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, staging

Our app has two targets, with separate Bundle Ids for the production and staging app:

```
com.myCompany.production
com.myCompany.staging
```

We have used TestFlight to test our app internally, but only at the later stages - we were testing **`com.myCompany.production`** app, whose API calls were hitting the production server.

Now we want to test earlier in the process, we want our internal users to test the **`com.myCompany.staging`** app.

Is creating a new app on iTunes Connect the only way to do this? I'm just concerned that I will be creating a 'fake' app which will never be released. What is the recommeneded way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two alternatives, adhoc distribution with an enterprise certificate and use a 3rd party service like fabric.io for distribution. Or use TestFlight, which we do, and have had no issues. We make sure that in the TestFlight reviewers notes we make clear that this version is just for beta testing. The only downside of this approach that we have found is that when you up the version number (not the build number) you have to resubmit for Beta review which can take anything from a few hours to a couple of days.

Comment: So you guys created new App in iTunesConnect for staging?

Comment: Yes, that's what we do.

Answer (score -1):

I had faced the same problem. The fix that worked for me was:

Create a hidden page for server configuration in the Mobile app

End User doesn't see this page this for dev purpose.

In my case I had created a hidden page in that we can manually enter the host IP address before login to the particular server.

To access this page I have a hidden button on the login page which only developers and testers know by long press that button u can access the page and change the server dynamically

If you want more security then add another page including password protection.

Note : Make sure the app will point to the production server by default.

So the flow will be like

Install app -> Long press the hidden button -> Enter password to change the ip -> Password correct -> change the IP to test server -> Login -> Enjoy

With this, you need not change the bundle ID each time u take build.This is Easy to maintain only one app rather than having different apps for different servers.