# How to keep Staging analytics/data out of Production for App Store deployment

Tags: android, ios, deployment, configuration, testflight

Once a build is submitted to the Apple Store/TestFlight or Google Play, that specific build can't be changed.

I take that to mean a Production build must be submitted, configured for the Production environment.

But then how would that same build be able to point to a Staging environment (for TestFlight or Google Play Alpha/Beta testing)? and then when approved reconfigured to point to Production before promotion to the App Store?

How do I support both a Staging and Production environment in a single build?

An example, would be for analytics where staging metrics shouldn't go to production or Q/A users whose data should reside on a Staging database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Separate apps in TestFlight for production and staging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36081602/separate-apps-in-testflight-for-production-and-staging)

Comment: Another possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73821262/organize-dev-staging-and-prod-environment-on-testflight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different approaches to deal with this. Part of this depends on your needs. For example, if you want to to be able to point to stage with a production build.

An easy approach is to use the `Debug` and `Release` configurations as your means of separating the two. In other words, builds built using the Debug configuration will point to stage and builds built with `Release` point to prod.

You can certainly pimp this out if you want. For example, you can have your `Debug` build actually be configurable to change environments.

Control of this is done with compile time flags such as DEBUG. So your code would be something like:

```
#if DEBUG
    // Do Staging environment setup here
#else
    // Do Prod environment setup here
#endif
```

It can be helpful to do this through some object to limit the places in code you need to discern between environments.

Note this is also a common way of handling 3rd Party services you may use for analytics, etc which have different keys for QA/prod.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So the two environments would be hardcoded into the build itself with macros flags. But does that mean I would need to rebuild and resubmit a RELEASE build after first building and submitting a DEBUG build?

Comment: This depends on your goal. Are these for all test builds? Typically you only submit Release for your app store submission. You should never submit Debug for App Store submission (to put on sale). If you need to be able to have a test build out there that can do both, then you need to implement some for of choosing system. Invariably at some point you are going to have to test prod. For that you would have to issue release builds to your tester. As you don't seem to be overly familiar with doing this, I would recommend you keep things as simple/basic as possible.

Comment: Right, the final build must be RELEASE. The confusion is how to submit a DEBUG build and promote it from Staging to Production without creating a new RELEASE build. But I guess you're saying that specific DEBUG builds must be created for TestFlight that aren't intended for RELEASE and that its inevitable (or just simpler and advisable) if QA does do final tests against a RELEASE build configured for Production.

Comment: I would not say a Debug build must be created for TF. It is just helpful to help debug it a bit easier. You can always submit a Release build for TF if you wanted. It is really up to you on if you want to send Release to TF for your last testing prior to Apple submission. Many times, this is not a bad thing to do. Simplest would be Debug build -> TF, Release build -> App Store. If you want more coverage Debug -> TF, Release -> TF (for final validation), Release -> App Store (once validated). If you wanted to be more complicated you can have Debug be able to switch between STG and PROD.

Comment: Keep it simple. Start with 1. Once comfortable go to 2. Maybe 3 later on. It will be easier to grok once you start doing it.